# Record calls in RingCentral after RingOut API

Tags: java, ringcentral

I am trying to record the call legs for the RingOut API in Java.

From RingCentral API documentation, I understand that the URL should be "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/accountId/telephony/sessions/telephonySessionId/parties/partyId/recordings", however, I don't see the "telephony" object in Java SDK.

Can someone guide me with recording call legs with RingOut API in Java.

Comment: HI, You need to fetch telephony session id from create ring out call API (https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/accountId/telephony/call-out). It will return the session object and it has id (sessionid). After that you can pass account id, partyid and telephonySessionId in createRecording API.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch telephony session id from create ring out call API 
https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Call-Control/createCallOutCallSession[1](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Call-Control/createCallOutCallSession). It will return the session object and it has id (`sessionid`). After that you can pass account id, `partyid` and `telephonySessionId` in createRecording API.

```
 {
   "session": {
      "creationTime": "2019-08-19T11:42:21Z",
      "id": "s-54a38392c79849dab4a25fe8040edd53",
      "origin": {
         "type": "Call"
      },
      "parties": [
         {
            "direction": "Outbound",
            "from": {
               "deviceId": "803469127021",
               "extensionId": "297277020",
               "name": "John Smith",
               "phoneNumber": "+18885287464"
            },
            "id": "p-54a38392c79849dab4a25fe8040edd53-1",
            "muted": false,
            "owner": {
               "accountId": "37439510",
               "extensionId": "297277020"
            },
            "standAlone": false,
            "status": {
               "code": "Setup"
            },
            "to": {
               "phoneNumber": "+79817891689"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```